# Google Maps not loading at certain times

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, netsuite

Google maps is integrated with NetSuite. The map loads after the click of a button but sometimes the map doesn't load. Most of the time in the afternoon between 3pm-5pm PHT. What's the cause of this?

Comment: no errors were returned btw

Comment: Sounds like you are reaching your daily quota and map is unavailable until quota reset that happens at 0:00 PST. Can you check your usage in the developer console? How many map loads you have in the graph?

Comment: @xomena about less than 2000 map loads a day. but i have the searchbox and places list of google maps. is there a way that i can monitor all counts of the api? and how does the count work? per user, per api key or per page load? thanks

Comment: For places the quota is counted against the corresponding web service. By default, the daily quota for Places API web service is 1000 daily requests. You should enable billing to have up to [150 000 daily requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage) for Places free of charge.